# AsyncTask to Post Json array Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

My Asynctask code..

```
private class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        Cursor cursor = mydb.getDat();

        JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

            for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
            {
                if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                        {

                            //  Log.d("Data", cursor.getString(i) );
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );

                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PHOTO)));
                            //  Log.d("pic",bitmap.toString());
                            String en= encodeToBase64(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,10);

                            //  Log.d("dn",en);

                            rowObject.put("pic",en);





                        }
                        else
                        {



                            rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                        }
                    }
                    catch( Exception e )
                    {
                        //   Log.d("Data", e.getMessage()  );
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("Final Json", resultSet.toString() );

        return resultSet;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
```

My code to send json to server..

```
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    server_url, new  TestAsync.execute(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

How can i use Async task to return json to post it to the server.How can i resolve this issue.The above code shows error in the post code under `execte()`.
How can i resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `TestAsync.execute()` which return `AsyncTask` to `JsonArrayRequest`. use `onPostExecute` for passing data to sever returned from `doInBackground` :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                server_url,result,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
}
```

If `TestAsync` is separate class then create [custom listener](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners) using `interface` for sending data from `onPostExecute` in Activity.

Comment: @Tom : No, do yourself and if getting any issue then tell we will try to help you